# How to stretch the content of Callisto CustomDialog?

Tags: windows-store-apps, customdialog, callisto

I am having a hard time figuring out how CustomDialog determines the width of its content. Appended is the code copied from Callisto's test app with two HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" added. Nothing stretches.  I want to stretch the content (e.g. StackPanel). I also tried assigning a value to the Width attribute of the StackPanel.   It seems that CustomDialog has some algorithm to pick a maximum width.  No matter what you do, its content will not exceed that width. Could anyone shed some light on this?

```
<!-- Example use of the CustomDialog control -->
<callisto:CustomDialog x:FieldModifier="public" x:Name="LoginDialog" 
                    Title="Bacon Terms and Conditions" 
                    Background="Teal" BackButtonVisibility="Visible" BackButtonClicked="LoginDialog_BackButtonClicked_1"
                    HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
    <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,8" FontSize="14.6667" FontWeight="SemiLight" TextWrapping="Wrap">
        Bacon sausage frankfurter tenderloin turkey salami andouille bresaola. Venison salami prosciutto, pork belly turducken tri-tip spare ribs chicken strip steak fatback shankle tongue boudin andouille. Meatloaf salami pork ground round turkey jerky meatball ball tip, filet mignon fatback flank prosciutto shank. Turkey boudin ham hock, filet mignon tri-tip bresaola tongue venison spare ribs meatloaf flank beef pancetta. Leberkas turducken flank ground round biltong chuck bacon kielbasa. Beef pastrami meatball, short loin venison swine pork loin shank meatloaf spare ribs.
        </TextBlock>
        <CheckBox Margin="0,0,0,8" Foreground="White" Content="I agree to the Terms and Conditions of Bacon" />
        <TextBlock Margin="0,0,0,8" FontSize="14.6667" FontWeight="SemiLight" Text="Enter your name for acceptance" />
        <callisto:WatermarkTextBox HorizontalAlignment="Left" Watermark="Type your name" Width="400" Height="35" />
        <StackPanel Margin="0,20,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Orientation="Horizontal">
            <Button Content="OK" Width="90" Margin="0,0,20,0" />
            <Button Content="CANCEL" Width="190" Click="DialogCancelClicked" />
        </StackPanel>
    </StackPanel>
</callisto:CustomDialog>
```

Comment: Try `HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"`

Comment: I have just tried per your tip.  Unfortunately, it does not make any difference.

Comment: Next thing to try is using a `Grid` instead of a `StackPanel`. `StackPanel`s generally have issues requesting as much space as they are given. `Grid`s do not have this problem.

Comment: I tried Grid before asking the question.  I have just tried it again with HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" of CustomDialog this time.  Unfortunately, it remains the same.

Comment: From reading the source, it seems that his `Style` doesn't seem to make the `ContentPresenter` inherit the `ContentAlignment` properties from the templated parent. I'm adding a possible solution as an answer because it is too large to fit here.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your persistent help. Look forward to your answer.  It would be even better if you could modify Callisto to improve it in this regard. The way I am dealing with it now is to set a TextBlcok to a very large value to force CustomDialog to take the largest width so that the width will not change upon the change of the TextBlock's content.

Comment: That is one way to do it, certainly. And, if this ends up working for you (I've posted it), then I'll propose it as an issue and solution on the GitHub.

Answer (score 1):

Currently, the default style does not seem to support this. [Here is the current default style (based on the GitHub).](https://github.com/timheuer/callisto/blob/master/src/Callisto/themes/Generic.xaml)

```
    <Style TargetType="local:CustomDialog">
    <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False" />
    <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource CustomDialogBorderThemeThickness}"/>
    <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource CustomDialogBorderThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="BackButtonVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource CustomDialogBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomDialog">
                <Popup x:Name="PART_RootPopup" IsLightDismissEnabled="False" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsOpen}">
                    <Grid x:Name="PART_RootGrid" Background="#72000000">
                        <Border x:Name="PART_BannerBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                            <Grid x:Name="PART_DialogGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                <Grid.Resources>
                                    <Style x:Key="DialogBackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                        <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                                        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26.66667"/>
                                        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="BackButton"/>
                                        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Back"/>
                                        <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.ItemType" Value="Navigation Button"/>
                                        <Setter Property="Template">
                                            <Setter.Value>
                                                <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                    <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Width="30" Height="30">
                                                        <Grid Margin="-3,-5,0,0">
                                                            <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0D4;" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=PART_DialogGrid, Path=Background}"/>
                                                            <TextBlock x:Name="NormalGlyph" Text="{ThemeResource SettingsFlyoutBackButtonGlyph}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=PART_DialogGrid, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}"/>
                                                            <TextBlock x:Name="ArrowGlyph" Text="&#xE0C4;" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=PART_DialogGrid, Path=Background}" Opacity="0"/>
                                                        </Grid>
                                                        <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                                                        <Rectangle
                        x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                        IsHitTestVisible="False"
                        Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                        StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                        StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                        Opacity="0"
                        StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                                                        <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BackButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ElementName=PART_DialogGrid, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}"/>
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ArrowGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                    <ColumnDefinition/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                <Border Grid.Column="1" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <StackPanel Margin="13,19,13,25" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" MaxWidth="680">
                                        <local:DynamicTextBlock Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}" x:Name="PART_Title" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.6667" FontWeight="Light" Margin="0,0,0,8" />
                                        <ContentPresenter Margin="0" x:Name="PART_Content" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}" />
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_BackButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,24,0,0"
                                    Style="{StaticResource DialogBackButtonStyle}" Command="{TemplateBinding BackButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding BackButtonCommandParameter}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding BackButtonVisibility}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Here is my thought for a solution. I've included it as an explicitly declared property of the `CustomDialog` in question. You may be able to add it to your project directly so it overrides it in all instances, or declare it statically and reference it in all of your `CustomDialog`s.

I also changed the namespace references to mimic yours. (`local` -> `callisto`)

```
<callisto:CustomDialog ...>

....

    <callisto:CustomDialog.Style>
            <Style TargetType="callisto:CustomDialog">
                <Setter Property="IsOpen" Value="False" />
                <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="{ThemeResource CustomDialogBorderThemeThickness}"/>
                <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="{ThemeResource CustomDialogBorderThemeBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="BackButtonVisibility" Value="Collapsed" />
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="{ThemeResource CustomDialogBackgroundThemeBrush}" />
                <Setter Property="Template">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <ControlTemplate TargetType="callisto:CustomDialog">
                            <Popup x:Name="PART_RootPopup" IsLightDismissEnabled="False" IsOpen="{TemplateBinding IsOpen}">
                                <Grid x:Name="PART_RootGrid" Background="#72000000">
                                    <Border x:Name="PART_BannerBorder" BorderBrush="{TemplateBinding BorderBrush}" BorderThickness="{TemplateBinding BorderThickness}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                        <Grid x:Name="PART_DialogGrid" Background="{TemplateBinding Background}" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                            <Grid.Resources>
                                                <Style x:Key="DialogBackButtonStyle" TargetType="Button">
                                                    <Setter Property="MinWidth" Value="0"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="Segoe UI Symbol"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FontWeight" Value="Normal"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="26.66667"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.AutomationId" Value="BackButton"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.Name" Value="Back"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="AutomationProperties.ItemType" Value="Navigation Button"/>
                                                    <Setter Property="Template">
                                                        <Setter.Value>
                                                            <ControlTemplate TargetType="Button">
                                                                <Grid x:Name="RootGrid" Width="30" Height="30">
                                                                    <Grid Margin="-3,-5,0,0">
                                                                        <TextBlock x:Name="BackgroundGlyph" Text="&#xE0D4;" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=PART_DialogGrid, Path=Background}"/>
                                                                        <TextBlock x:Name="NormalGlyph" Text="{ThemeResource SettingsFlyoutBackButtonGlyph}" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=PART_DialogGrid, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}"/>
                                                                        <TextBlock x:Name="ArrowGlyph" Text="&#xE0C4;" Foreground="{Binding ElementName=PART_DialogGrid, Path=Background}" Opacity="0"/>
                                                                    </Grid>
                                                                    <Rectangle
                                    x:Name="FocusVisualWhite"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualWhiteStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                    StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                    StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                    Opacity="0"
                                    StrokeDashOffset="1.5"/>
                                                                    <Rectangle
                                    x:Name="FocusVisualBlack"
                                    IsHitTestVisible="False"
                                    Stroke="{ThemeResource FocusVisualBlackStrokeThemeBrush}"
                                    StrokeEndLineCap="Square"
                                    StrokeDashArray="1,1"
                                    Opacity="0"
                                    StrokeDashOffset="0.5"/>

                                                                    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Normal" />
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerOver">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{ThemeResource BackButtonPointerOverBackgroundThemeBrush}"/>
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Pressed">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="BackgroundGlyph" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Foreground">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{Binding ElementName=PART_DialogGrid, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}"/>
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="ArrowGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="NormalGlyph"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="0"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Disabled">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetName="RootGrid" Storyboard.TargetProperty="Visibility">
                                                                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="Collapsed"/>
                                                                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                                            <VisualStateGroup x:Name="FocusStates">
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Focused">
                                                                    <Storyboard>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualWhite"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                                                        <DoubleAnimation
                                        Storyboard.TargetName="FocusVisualBlack"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Opacity"
                                        To="1"
                                        Duration="0"/>
                                                                    </Storyboard>
                                                                </VisualState>
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="Unfocused" />
                                                                <VisualState x:Name="PointerFocused" />
                                                            </VisualStateGroup>
                                                        </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
                                                    </Grid>
                                                </ControlTemplate>
                                            </Setter.Value>
                                        </Setter>
                                    </Style>
                                </Grid.Resources>
                                <Border VerticalAlignment="Center">
                                    <StackPanel Margin="13,19,13,25" HorizontalAlignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}" Width="{TemplateBinding Width}" MaxWidth="680">
                                        <callisto:DynamicTextBlock Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}" x:Name="PART_Title" Text="{TemplateBinding Title}" FontFamily="Segoe UI" FontSize="26.6667" FontWeight="Light" Margin="0,0,0,8" />
                                        <ContentPresenter Margin="0" x:Name="PART_Content" Foreground="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, Path=Background, Converter={StaticResource ColorContrast}}" HorizontalAllignment="{TemplateBinding HorizontalContentAlignment}"/>
                                    </StackPanel>
                                </Border>
                                <Button x:Name="PART_BackButton" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="0,24,0,0"
                                    Style="{StaticResource DialogBackButtonStyle}" Command="{TemplateBinding BackButtonCommand}" CommandParameter="{TemplateBinding BackButtonCommandParameter}" Visibility="{TemplateBinding BackButtonVisibility}"/>
                            </Grid>
                        </Border>
                    </Grid>
                </Popup>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>

....

</callisto:CustomDialog>
```

Hope this helps and happy coding!

Edit: Wrong style! Fixed it, sorry for that.

Edit: One last thing to try, removed the column definitions from the content definition. This may have an effect on the title positioning, so you may need to play around with it at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks again.  I am getting the following error: "Cannot apply a Style with TargetType 'Callisto.Controls.Flyout' to an object of type 'Callisto.Controls.CustomDialog'"

Comment: Snap! You're correct, I copied the wrong Style! The solution is still the same (with a different style), but I will fix my answer.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the fix.  I feel we are much closer to the solution now.  I currently getting the following error: Error 21 The property 'HorizontalAllignment' was not found in type 'ContentPresenter'.

Comment: I have just noticed it is just a typo. Now, I am getting errors like the following: "Cannot find a Resource with the Name/Key CustomDialogBorderThemeThickness".  There are a lot of resources that cannot be found.

Comment: The fastest fix is to go to the link in the answer to the Github and copy the merged ThemeDictionaries at the top into your solution.

Comment: I have just merged generic.xaml, and the app runs now.  Unfortunately, the content still does not stretch.  This is the TestApp in the package of Callisto.

Comment: Added one last thing to try. Changed the grid column definitions at the bottom.

Comment: Thank you for your persistent help. I have removed the column definitions per your suggestion.  Unfortunately, the issue remains.